# free plotting software with high zoom in resolution

Tags: matlab, graph, gnuplot

I use gnuplot to generate graphs. But recently, I generate some graphs with lots of points (around 10^6) and I have to zoom in many times to see the each individual point. So I have to switch to matlab which allows me to zoom in many times until I see each individual point. But the problem is that it is not free.

Is there any free software that allows me to preserve the resolution after I zoom in? (or maybe there are some hidden way of using gnuplot that I am not aware of)

Comment: What kind of plotting style do you refer to? Gnuplot doesn't have any problems with zooming, unless you use a pixel-based output format which, of course, looses information (which is however the same with matlab or any other graphic software). Please be more detailled about your use case. Is it is, your question is too broad.

Comment: Any format that allows unlimited zoom in.

Comment: Gnuplot's wxt/qt/windows terminal allows you to zoom in as you want, like Matlab. For a saved graph, I don't think there is a format that either Matlab or gnuplot can produce. You have to rescale the whole plot, how should a graphics viewer know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use scalable vector graphics to allow zoom in to plot. You can do this in gnuplot by

```
set term svg enhanced mouse size 1920, 1080
```

You can adjust the size according to your requirements and `svg` will allow you to zoom indefinitely.